# define getter without setter ecma6 - react

Tags: class, reactjs, compiler-errors, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

React-ecma6 dosent seem to allow defining getters without setters
Is there a way of defining a getter only method and changing a value through any other method?

```
import React from 'react';
export default class GetterOnly extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._is_on = false;
    }

    on() {
        this._is_on = true;
    }

    get is_on() {
        return this._is_on;
    }

    render() {

    }
}
var _getter = new GetterOnly()
_getter.on();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property is_on of #GetterOnly
>   which has only a getter
>
> patchProperty @   makeAssimilatePrototype.js:21 (anonymous
>   function) @   makeAssimilatePrototype.js:52 (anonymous
>   function) @   makeAssimilatePrototype.js:51
>   reconcileWithStoredPrototypes @   makeAssimilatePrototype.js:50
>   assimilatePrototype   @   makeAssimilatePrototype.js:63
>   patchReactClass   @   makePatchReactClass.js:40
>   makeHot   @   makeMakeHot.js:33 makeExportsHot    @   makeExportsHot.js:44
>   (anonymous function)  @   GetterOnly.js:139 (anonymous
>   function) @   GetterOnly.js:139 (anonymous function)  @   GetterOnly.js:140
>   (anonymous function)  @   app.js:5062
>   **webpack_require**   @   app.js:556 fn   @   app.js:87 (anonymous function)  @   page.js:35 (anonymous function) @   page.js:81 (anonymous
>   function) @   page.js:82 (anonymous function) @   app.js:5056
>   **webpack_require**   @   app.js:556 fn   @   app.js:87 (anonymous function)  @   Routes.js:19 (anonymous function)   @   Routes.js:52
>   (anonymous function)  @   Routes.js:53 (anonymous function)   @   app.js:4438
>   **webpack_require**   @   app.js:556 fn   @   app.js:87 (anonymous function)  @   makoVOD.js:19 (anonymous function)  @   makoVOD.js:62
>   (anonymous function)  @   makoVOD.js:63 (anonymous
>   function) @   app.js:1042
>   **webpack_require**   @   app.js:556 fn   @   app.js:87 (anonymous function)  @   multi_main:3 (anonymous function)   @   app.js:586
>   **webpack_require**   @   app.js:556 (anonymous function) @   app.js:579 (anonymous function) @   app.js:582

Comment: No, it is allowed - it's not a syntax error. The error message you got suggests that something did try to assign to `.is_on`, which throws an exception without a setter. Inspect the stack trace of the error to see where it is coming from.

Comment: this is a simplified version of the code, and it still shows an error:
`import React from 'react';
class GetterOnly extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props); 
 };
 
 get is_on() {
  return this._is_on;
 };

 render() {

 };
}

export default GetterOnly `

Comment: this seems to be an issue with the import/export modules

Comment: I am pretty sure that the exporting process does not set a property. Show us where you import and use the class. And please [edit] your post to include the stack trace.

Comment: console error added.
as for showing the import I only do this in the head of a different js:
import GetterOnly from 'components/subscription/getteronly';

Comment: I think I found the problem, it was in the webpack.hot... module.
Upgraded to vesion : 2.0.0-alpha and the error disappeared.
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasent React/Es6 reponsibility. It appeared to come from the nodejs - webpack.hot... module which I've used to auto transpile the code. 
I've Upgraded to vesion : 2.0.0-alpha and the error disappeared. 
its a known issue in - 
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/131

Answer (score -4):

The problem is that you're calling `on` as a function.  A getter makes the function look like a property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

So that last line should be `_getter.on` instead of `_getter.on()`.

Also, to make that `_is_on` variable private, you can define it outside of the class, like so:

```
import React from 'react';

let _is_on = false;

export default class GetterOnly extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    on() {
        _is_on = true;
    }

    get is_on() {
        return _is_on;
    }

    render() {

    }
}
var _getter = new GetterOnly()
_getter.on;
```

Now no one but the class can edit the variable.

Comment: `on` is method indeed and should be called. `let _is_on = false;` will share this flag between all instances.